# My 16 year old Lhasa

Tags: dogs, health, diet

My 16 year old Lhasa has a collapsed trachea. She weighs 21 lbs. Ideally , she should weigh 20lbs. How much raw meat and what supplements should I give her daily ? She has no other health issues.

Comment: Can you add some more information about why you think you should be changing her diet, and what the vet told you?

Answer (score 3):

This question has a lot of potential to be loaded...

I would also like to say that many dogs with a collapsed trachea are able to eat kibble just fine. You may have other reasons for wanting to switch.

You're on the right track that dogs need additional vitamins and minerals that are not found in a diet straight from the butcher's block. And some breeds have additional, breed-specific requirements.

But there's an additional complication in the meat itself - most meat, especially meat from the grocery store - is graded and rated to be safe when it is cooked. Eating raw meat always has a risk of parasites, and eating a diet purely of it is vastly increasing that very small chance. If you do decide to feed raw meat, you have to take extra care on this subject and where your meat comes from, especially with an elderly dog.

Figuring out what meat to get, what to add to it, how much to give, breed specific requirements... all of this is very time consuming and likely just as costly as alternative raw dog food that you can buy. Before you decide on making your own dog food, check out the different raw dog foods that you can buy online and have shipped to your pet. These foods will be safe from parasites, have all the nutrients and minerals, and have feeding guidelines already figured out. Most of these companies even have breed-specific foods and feeding guides, also.

I'm not certain on the guidelines for providing links, but a simple google search for "raw dog food online" should point you in the right direction to these companies. See if any meet your needs.